# pymongo adds the _id field to my dictionary on insertion

Tags: python, windows, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

Consider this example:

```
f = {'a': 'b'}
col.insert(f)
print f
```

, where `col` is a mongodb collection.

The above code will print something among the lines of:

```
{'a': 'b', '_id': ObjectId('5278bc183e8b1310247e047b')}
```

I know why mongo needs to add the `_id` field when inserting the document into the collection, but I don't understand why it has to modify the dictionary I pass as an argument. I would like my dictionary `f` to remain unmodified.

I know I can just `del f['_id']` after the insert, but is there any argument I can pass to `insert` that will make it not modify my dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the `manipulate` argument to `False`, e.g.:

```
col.insert(f, manipulate=False)
```

See http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert

Comment: When I first tried that before I posted the question I typed `f = {'a', 'b'}` creating a set instead of a dict and it resulted in an error... but yea... it does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the documentation on the [insert method](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=insert#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert) correctly, `manipulate` parameter is what you're looking for:

> If manipulate is True, the document(s) are manipulated using any SONManipulator instances that have been added to this Database. In this case an "_id" will be added if the document(s) does not already contain one and the "id" (or list of "_id" values for more than one document) will be returned. If manipulate is False and the document(s) does not include an "_id" one will be added by the server. The server does not return the "_id" it created so None is returned.